# Are gravitational waves dissipated and what is the mechanism?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, dissipation

I was amazed by the fact that we have been able to detect gravitational waves created thousands of year before they were observed. My surprise is that any wave phenomena I know it is always dissipated, so I thought gravitational waves would have been dissipated.

It is true that the waves would have been propagated through vacuum, but, if I understood properly relativity equations, the media is not a factor. Likely passing though gravity fields (starts? black holes?) will have something to do.

So, my question is, Is there any mechanism to dissipate gravitational waves? Can they, with our current knowledge, propagate without losing energy?