# How can gravitational waves dissipate the energy carried by them?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, energy, gravitational-waves

I am not an expert on GR or gravitational waves but i have been reading about them and i wondered about where and how do these gravitational waves dump their energy? I read that the black hole collision detected by LIGO had energy equivalent to the mass of 3 solar masses in the form of gravitational waves. So, my question is **where does this energy end up going?**

Comment: Are gravitational waves capable of doing work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Are gravitational waves dissipated and what is the mechanism?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235680/)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the question before. I only joined the site 2 days ago and it didn't come up while i was typing my question.

Comment: Can't the two questions merge somehow?

Comment: I'm going to answer the linked question now, then the questions can be merged.

Comment: @JohnRennie okay cool

Comment: @JohnRennie how do we merge the answers and comments from the two questions?

Comment: Do i just copy paste everything to the second question?

Comment: Aha there is [an even earlier duplicate here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235574/) so I've moved my answer to that one. You don't have to do anything. The site moderators will link the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy propagates circularly (if far enough like we are), and if it runs into some matter it interacts very weakly. We detected it because it transformed some amount (a very small part of its energy, that's why it was so hard to detect, people have tried for over 50 years, and only now have our detectors become sensitive enough) of its energy in moving, ever so slightly, the mirrors used in the detection apparatus, so it lost some energy. Without some energy transfer we would not have detected it ever. Equivalently, it shortened the distance traveled by the light in one leg, and increased it in the other leg of the interferometer used to detect the gravitational wave.

Comment: Doesn't the energy spread out radially instead oh circularly which would limit the energy transfer to a single plane and would severely decrease our chances of detecting such an event. Also, can you  please explain the process by which the wave transferred the energy to the detectors? Is it the only way by which gravitational waves may impart energy to matter?

Comment: Did the wave actually physically move the interferometer or did it just temporarily decrease and increase the space between the atoms of the legs?

Comment: @Aniansh it created a type vibrations.  That is why great care is taken to diminish external vibrations by suspending the detectors , so as not to get confused with the sought signal . The distances between the hanging  detectors temporarily changed , the space between them.

Comment: @Aniansh watch the first 45 minutes of this web cast https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_582rU6neLc . The detectors are suspended, the distance of kilometers changed with the passing of the wave

Comment: @annav okay I understand that part but what about the propagation? Doest the propagation happen in a single plane?

Comment: it is like light, very very weak light coming at the detector. plane wave at such distance from source.

Comment: Yes, it is radially out, when you are so far away. Sloppy wording, circularly. And yes, it is as Anna said, when you receive it so far away, like a plane wave, that's also why you can do a level of triangulation like you would with far-off IR, RF or light sources -- in reality you'd need 3 or 4 separated interferometers to locate in 3D, and if there's little separation in some dimension the accuracy in that dimension will suffer. For the GW150914 there were just two interferometers, so the location errors had a geometrical banana shaped form (it's been posted online, not here).